# Azure AD B2C passwordless sign in custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My organization needs passwordless with email authentication in sign in.
That mean user just needs to enter an email, then the system will send the one time passcode into that email & let user sign in.
I tried [this sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email) & it works for me.
what I want to customize is,in sign in page i want only login with email option to be there. currently it gives option to sign in with social account (facebook) . how can i disable this or remove it from login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just comment this line out：https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L71.

It will remove the option of social account (facebook) login.

Comment: Is it possible In azure B2C, like if some new user sign up ,we can approve it before user creation.???

Comment: @RohitChouhan What is "approve it before user creation"? Can you explain it in detail? If you don't mind, it's better to create a new post for this new question. That will attract the attention of more Azure B2C experts.

Comment: I am getting user identity authentication error while using this with ASP.NET core MVC.
Do we need to do some extra setting while using identity experience framework ?
Can you suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you also need to comment out everything that mentions Facebook:

- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L441
- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L1012
- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L1018
- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L22
- https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/passwordless-email/policy/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L91