# Azure AD B2C passwordless for only Local Account policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My base policy is based on the LocalAccount Starter Pack

I am referring to this [passwordless sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/passwordless-email) which is based on SocialAndLocalAccount Starter Pack

My question is similar to this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59642432/azure-ad-b2c-passwordless-sign-in-custom-policy). But the answers provided there are not updated as of now.

I am new to creating custom policies and am unable to decide what steps I need to remove from the user journey.

I did remove the Order = 3,4, and 6 but it gives me a Claim Error while signing in. Also, according to the passwordless sample, if an unknown user tries to sign in it should give a validation that user does not exist. Instead, it sends the OTP to the unknown user too.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove anything to do with Facebook, and remove anything to do with AlternativeSecurityId.

Comment: Will that be enough? because there were 7 user journey steps and if I understood correctly there are 3 related to social login.

Comment: I did remove the Order 3, 4, and 6 but it gives a Claim error while signing in. I have updated the question for more details

Comment: Step 6 you need to replace with "AAD-UserWriteUsingObjectId"